# Using set as a way to reorder iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I have two tuples `a` and `b` and also a dictionary `d`

```
a=('C', 'G')
b=('G', 'C') 
d={('G', 'C'): 'T'}
```

I want `d[a]` and `d[b]` to return `'T'`.

For that I used `set()` because I thought that `set()` was fixing the order of the elements of a iterable object (and removing the duplicates but I don't care about that).

So I did:

```
tuple(set(a)) in d  # return True
tuple(set(b)) in d  # return True
# I did tuple(set()) because set() alone is not hashable and so cannot be used directly
```

This works, until it doesn't. And so I discover than sometimes

```
set(('C', 'G'))
{'C', 'G'}
```

and sometimes it does not

```
set(('C', 'G'))
{'G', 'C'}
```

I understand that `set()` orders the element as it wants but I expected that the order would always be the same with a given set of elements.

So my questions are:

- Why it's not the case?
- How can I solve my initial problem?

Comment: Either use the `tuple(sorted(x))` as the key or `frozenset(x)`

Answer (score 0):

The set is built on some data structure that offers allows efficient checks of membership.  The consequence is that Python loses the original ordering specified in the code when instantiating this structure.

If you really only have the two labels, I would probably just explicitly specify both values.

```
a=('C', 'G')
b=('G', 'C') 
d={a: 'T', b: 'T'}
```

To solve a larger version of this problem, you will need to set the value of both order separately.  For a larger problem, I would use a comprehension with a double loop

```
lbls = ['a', 'b', 'c']
{(f, s):'T' for f in lbls for s in lbls if f != s}
```

Comment: I didn't mean this was the exact implementation, just an example of this sort of data structure.  Removed the reference.

Comment: Ah, ok. You meant "e.g." then, not "i.e.".

Answer (score 0):

Just use **sorted** tuples whenever you need to index your dict:

```
a = ('C', 'G')
b = ('G', 'C')
d = {tuple(sorted(a)): 'T'}
for tup in [a, b]:
   print( tup, d[tuple(sorted(tup))] )
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to normalize the keys by sorting them. When we look up, we also sort the keys before looking up.

```py
import collections.abc

def _normalize(key):
    """ Normalize a key (tuple) by sorting """
    key = tuple(sorted(key))
    return key

class TupleKeyDict(collections.abc.MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        temp_dict = dict(*args, **kwargs)
        self.dict = {
            _normalize(key): value
            for key, value in temp_dict.items()
        }

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        value = self.dict[_normalize(key)]
        return value

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.dict[_normalize(key)] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.dict[_normalize(key)]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.dict)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dict)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.dict)
```

```py
>>> tkd = TupleKeyDict(d)
>>> tkd
{('C', 'G'): 'T'}

>>> tkd['C', 'G']
'T'

>>> tkd['G', 'C']
'T'

>>> tkd.get(('X', 'Y')) is None
True

>>> tkd['X', 'C'] = 'cx'
>>> tkd['C', 'X']
'cx'
```

## Discussion

We cannot use sets as the keys before sets are mutable (changeable) therefore does not have a constant hash--a requirement for being a key. My approach is to create a specialized dictionary where the keys are sorted tuples which make looking up easier.

The `__init__` method takes in everything that you can pass into `dict()`. The `__repr__` method aids debugging. All other methods are there to fulfill the `collections.abc.MutableMapping` requirements.